# Google Sheets BigQuery Connector

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-formula

I have BigQuery view with orders/sales data by date connected to my google sheets project via default BigQuery Data connector

And simple formula to get all order on specific date
`=COUNTIFS(orders_view!date;">="&C$19; orders_view!date;"<"&(C$19+1))` to make it look kinda like that:
[image]

But every time I change the date I want to get orders by, I have to click `Apply` near the cell with formula:
[image]

Is there any solution to auto apply query? Exporting full BQ data to Sheets is not an option there are more than 10 million cells.

Comment: One option is do the calculation in BigQuery View and then in connected sheet there's facility to schedule the refresh in the connected sheet tab. hope this helps

Comment: Nope( I have raw data in BigQuery View and to need use google sheets to visualise that data

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL? The recommended practice for big data is to do the calculation in BIgQuery using SQL and export only the result to Google Sheets for your visualization.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a great idea to use google sheets if you're working with millions of rows of data. For Big Data, it is recommended to use Big Query. You can use SQL to do your analysis and load only the results to a table then connect this to Sheets if you require to do visualization using Google Sheets.

To learn more about SQL syntax, refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax)

Comment: But how am I gonna do all calculations in BQ, if all the parameters and filters are in google sheets?

Comment: I want to connect raw data via BQ connector and then visualise it. It works. But as I said in my question, I have to click Apply every time I change parameters. Is there any way to auto apply or something?